# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'prevState.intervalTimer')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

my expo app stopped after a mess up with prettier. I pulled a new branch, disabled any code formating on vscode and even though `npm install` now needs `--legacy-peer-deps` to work things are starting to get fixed one by one. Now it's giving an error code of `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'prevState.intervalTimer')` that I can't seem to be able to figure out why it's throwing this error.

This is where I have used `'prevState.intervalTimer')` (in my home screen)

```
  componentDidUpdate ( prevProps, prevState )
  {
    const name = ( this.props.currentWorkoutPlan || {} ).name;
    const prevName = ( prevProps.currentWorkoutPlan || {} ).name;
    if ( name !== prevName )
    {
      this.props.navigation.setParams( { currentWorkoutPlanName: name } );
    }

    if ((prevState.intervalTimer || {}).rest_time === this.props.rest_time) {
      !!this.horizRef.current && this.horizRef.current.scrollTo({ animated: false, x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
  }
```

Nowhere else in my code do I have a `prevState.intervalTimer`

Part of my `interval timer` reducer is this:

```
    case TIMER.START_REST_TIMER: {
      const { initialTime, exercise } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        initial_rest_time: initialTime,
        rest_time: initialTime,
        rest_exercise: exercise
      }
    }
    case TIMER.TICK_REST_TIMER: {
      return {
          ...state,
          rest_time: state.rest_time - 1
      }
    }
    case TIMER.STOP_REST_TIMER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        rest_time: state.initial_rest_time,
        initial_rest_time: null,
        rest_exercise: null
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default intervalTimer;
```

and I have it imported via `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => ( {
  rest_time: state.intervalTimer.rest_time,
  rest_exercise: state.intervalTimer.rest_exercise
} );
```

all of these codes have stayed the same and I've compared them to my old code and I don't know why this is failing but it's error that's throwing at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's null initially so you can handle that by using the optional chaining operator.

```
if ((prevState?.intervalTimer || {}).rest_time === this.props.rest_time) {
      !!this.horizRef.current && this.horizRef.current.scrollTo({ animated: false, x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
```